# Use of "would" when describing habits in present

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

My question pertains to one specific form of usage of "would".
Is is inappropriate or even incorrect or, *a fortiori*, not understandable, if we use (read as: *on utilise*) "would" when referring to present habits, if we do not want to render a general statement, but rather a specific, concrete, to-one-person-relating one; when we would like to describe one´s typical approach or typical characteristic, one´s peculiarities.

Thank you! :)

Examples:

(1) Here I think "would" is more appropriate.
*It is 8 a.m. My friend would (usually) get in a hurry when having overslept.* 
vs.
*It is 8 a.m. My friend will (usually) get in a hurry when having overslept.*

(2) Here I think "will" is more appropriate.
*Sun would (always) rise in the east.*
vs.
*Sun will (always) rise in the east.*

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: Here you are :).

Comment: This is not as simple to answer as it might appear. More information is needed. Using will or would can depend on factors such as when one is speaking. If it is long after the event when recalling someone's past habits, then 'would' would seem to fit? Please could you supply more information for each example, who is speaking, when etc? What is the status of the words in brackets? In the first example the gram mar is not perfectly correct in either example. What exactly do you mean by 'get in a hurry'. Do you mean 'hurry'? 'My friend will hurry if he oversleeps'. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, I mean hurry.

Comment: And that is exactly the point - all depends on the concrete cummunicational situation! Other possibilities for the senteces may be: Tom would do something like that (when facing something) for the first example; A friend will always help you (if you are in need) for the second one.

Comment: I mean, it is gramatically odd to me, too :). This question is rather academical...

Comment: But my first example (It is 8 a. m. ....) should not be construed as conditional sentence, it should be construed rather as the statement of fact.

Comment: Habitual "would" only applies to ***past*** contexts. For present, future, or "timeless" contexts, it's *"Usually on Sunday mornings I **will** stay in bed until midday with the newspaper"* (or just simple present ***I stay in bed***).

Answer (score 1):

Will in both cases: It's 8 a.m.; what your friend will do is not yet in the past. The Sun continues to exist, and will rise in the East.

Comment: Or the simple present, "the sun rises…" etc., but yes; *would* makes the whole clause read as if it is about the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example 'Tom would do something like this' would be correct concerning the present only if it is in the context of an unreal hypothetical. I.e. Tom isn't doing it; he's not here to ask, but based on my knowledge of him and his behaviour in this present situation he 'would' do such and such.  This would be the basic grammar characteristic of back-stepping a tense in unreal contexts.